# Headset microphone and laptop inbuilt microphone input is not recognized and wierd noise with video recording in native camera app

Tags: graphic-drivers, audio, videos

1 am using Acer Swift 3 - SF314-55G. It has
Intel i5 8th Gen
2GB of NVIDIA Geforce MX250 dedicated graphics.
8 Gb RAM
512 GB SSD

These are the problems I am facing with the fresh installation.

1. Headset microphone and laptop inbuilt microphone input is not recognized.
2. After Installation and update following drivers installation is suggested in the app center. Do I need to install them?
   [image: Available Drivers]

**Update #2**

These are the results

```
sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de9 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d52 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5003 (rev 01)

sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic

sudo journalctl -xb
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-07-12 18:29:30 IST, end at Sun 2020-07-12 22:20:15 IST. --
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xd6, date = 2020-04-27
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: Linux version 5.3.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubun
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic root=UUID=907427fa-236a-
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compact
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000078b46fff] usable
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078b47000-0x000000007a390fff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a391000-0x000000007a40dfff] ACPI data
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a40e000-0x000000007a530fff] ACPI NVS
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a531000-0x000000007ab5efff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ab5f000-0x000000007ac0dfff] type 20
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ac0e000-0x000000007ac0efff] usable
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ac0f000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Jul 12 18:57:07 vishal-Swift-SF314-55G kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed03fff] reserved
```

Comment: Please provide results which these commands below will display. sudo lspci sudo update-initramfs -u sudo journalctl -xb

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

To restart machine type:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

If after restart there will be no sound, type in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add

```
snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950
```

to the end of this file, save with Ctrl+o and exit with Ctrl+x.

Restart machine.

Comment: No success. This command didn't worked. sudo systemctl restart Too few arguments. All the rest 3 commands I tried as you suggested. But microphone is not detected. Just to clarify my issue once again - I am able to listen to audio output through headphone and laptop speakers but not able to record any audio or talk to anyone, i.e., no sound is coming in recorded audio or Video.

Comment: Can you try to type in terminal:

sudo apt install pulseaudio pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2

Comment: Sound troubleshooting procedure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure Elementary OS is Ubuntu based, so it will work.

Comment: Additionally type pulseaudio in applications and check settings for each input device.

Comment: It didn't worked. After the command all the default apps that comes preloded on Ubuntu 20.04 got installed.

Comment: I provided you possible solutions. Check all of them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I found some links dealing with similar issue

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082994/acer-swift-3-microphone-not-working-with-ubuntu-18-04

https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/fv85p5/inbuilt_mic_and_headphone_jack_mic_not_working_on/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Internal microphone not working on Acer swift3 alc256 - Technical Issues and Assistance / Drivers - Manjaro Linux Forum
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/internal-microphone-not-working-on-acer-swift3-alc256/137484